# Bash Script - If Else statement evaluates TRUE

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, nmap, nrpe

I would like to seek your advice on this peculiar problem I had with this script that I wrote.

It has Single Mode where it checks for 1 server or Multi Mode where you can point it to a text file containing multiple lines of hostname and ip address per lines.

For each set of hostname and ip address,

- It will pings the ip address, (ping -c 4 )
- run nmap {sudo nmap -Pn -p  )
- check if nagios agent is installed using the check_nrpe plugin.

The original version runs perfectly good. However, for a particular server, it evaluates both conditions for IF and ELSE as true for the function where nmap is run.

Below I provide the script and also the output of bash -x, with the p address redacted. I have bolded the output that baffles me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Usage () {

echo -e "Usage Info"

}


while getopts ":H:S:T:f:p:PMN" opt;
do
    case $opt in
        H)  # Host IP Address. Use this option if checking only single host. 
            HostAddr=$OPTARG
            RunMode=1
            ;;

        S)  # Host Name. Use this option if checking only single host. 
            HostName=$OPTARG
            ;; 

        f)  # absolute path to the text file containing list of IP Addresses. Use this option if checking multiple hosts. 
            HostFile=$OPTARG
            RunMode=2 
            ;;

        P)  # Ping the hostnames.   
            PingOn=1 
            ;;

        M)  # Check using NMAP if specified port is open. 
            CheckPort=1
            ;;

        p)  # Specify port to be used by NMAP. 
            NPort=$OPTARG
            ;;

        N)  # Check if NRPE agent is installed and configured.
            CheckNRPEOn=1
            ;;

        ?)  # Error in option. Shows Usage guide. 
            Usage
            ;;
    esac
done


cmd_Ping () {
    PingResult=$(ping -c 4 "$HostIP" | grep 'transmitted' | awk -F ' ' '{ print $4 }')
    if [[ "$PingResult" -eq 4 ]]; then
        PingStatus='OK'
    else
        PingStatus='FAILED'
    fi

    PingOut=$(echo -e "Ping: $PingStatus")
}


cmd_NMAP () {
    PortStatus=$(sudo nmap -Pn -p "$NPort" "$HostIP" | grep "$NPort" | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }')
            
    if [[ "$PortStatus" = 'open' ]]; then
        PortOut=$(echo -e "Port $NPort: OPEN")

    elif [[ "$PortStatus" = 'filtered' ]]; then 
        PortOut=$(echo -e "Port $NPort: FILTERED")

    elif [[ "$PortStatus" = 'closed' ]]; then 
        PortOut=$(echo -e "Port $NPort: CLOSED")    
    
    else
        PortOut=$(echo -e "Port $NPort: ERROR")
    fi
}


cmd_TNET () {
    PortStatus=$(echo -e '\x1dclose\x0d' | timeout 5 sudo telnet "$HostIP" "$NPort" | grep Connected | awk -F' ' '{ print $1}')
    
    if [[ "$PortStatus" = 'Connected' ]]; then 
        PortOut=$(echo -e "Port $NPort: OPEN")
    else 
        PortOut=$(echo -e "Port $NPort: FAILED")
    fi
}


cmd_NRPE () {
    NRPEtmp=$(sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H "$HostIP")
    NRPEnix=$(echo "$NRPEtmp" | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }')
    NRPEwin=$(echo "$NRPEtmp" | cut -d ' ' -f4-)
    if [[ "$NRPEnix" = 'NRPE' ]] || [[ "$NRPEwin" = 'seem to be doing fine...' ]]; then
        NRPEOut=$(echo -e "NRPE: Configured")
    else
        NRPEOut=$(echo -e "NPRE: Not Configured")
    fi
}


mode_Multi () {    # Multiple IP Address Mode 

    while read -r HostInfo;
    do
        HostName=$(echo "$HostInfo" | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }')
        HostIP=$(echo "$HostInfo" | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }')
        if [[ $PingOn -eq 1 ]]; then
            cmd_Ping
        else   # ($PingOn -ne 1 )
            PingOut='N/A'
        fi 

        if [[ "$CheckPort" -eq 1 ]]; then
            cmd_NMAP
        else   # ($CheckPort -ne 1)
            PortOut='N/A' 
        fi

        if [[ "$CheckNRPEOn" -eq 1 ]]; then
            cmd_NRPE
            NRPEOut='N/A'
        fi


        echo -e " $HostName, $HostIP, $PingOut, $PortOut, $NRPEOut"  
    done < "$HostFile"
}



mode_Single () {    # Single IP Address Mode 

    HostIP=$HostAddr

    if [[ $PingOn -eq 1 ]]; then
        cmd_Ping
    else   # ($PingOn -ne 1) 
        PingOut='N/A'
    fi 

    if [[ "$CheckPort" -eq 1 ]]; then
        cmd_NMAP
    else   # ($CheckPort -ne 1)
        PortOut='N/A' 
    fi

    if [[ "$CheckPort2" -eq 1 ]]; then 
        cmd_TNET
    else 
        PortOut='N/A'
    fi 

    if [[ "$CheckNRPEOn" -eq 1 ]]; then
        cmd_NRPE
    else  
        NRPEOut='N/A'
    fi

    echo -e "$HostName, $HostIP, $PingOut, $PortOut, $NRPEOut"      
}


if [[ "$RunMode" -eq 1 ]]; then 
    mode_Single 
else 
    mode_Multi
fi
```

and here is the output for Single Mode :

I would run this script like this :

`./HostChecker.sh -S <HostName> -H <HostIP> -PMN -p <port number>`

```
+ getopts :H:S:T:f:p:PMN opt
+ case $opt in
+ HostAddr=10.119.4.106
+ RunMode=1
+ getopts :H:S:T:f:p:PMN opt
+ case $opt in
+ PingOn=1
+ getopts :H:S:T:f:p:PMN opt
+ case $opt in
+ CheckNRPEOn=1
+ getopts :H:S:T:f:p:PMN opt
+ case $opt in
+ CheckPort=1
+ getopts :H:S:T:f:p:PMN opt
+ case $opt in
+ NPort=5666
+ getopts :H:S:T:f:p:PMN opt
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ mode_Single
+ HostIP=10.x.x.x 
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ cmd_Ping
++ ping -c 4 10.x.x.x 
++ grep transmitted
++ awk -F ' ' '{ print $4 }'
+ PingResult=0
+ [[ 0 -eq 4 ]]
+ PingStatus=FAILED
++ echo -e 'Ping: FAILED'
+ PingOut='Ping: FAILED'
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ cmd_NMAP
++ sudo nmap -Pn -p 5666 10.119.4.106
++ grep 5666
++ awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }'
+ PortStatus=filtered
+ [[ filtered = \o\p\e\n ]]
+ [[ filtered = \f\i\l\t\e\r\e\d ]]
++ echo -e 'Port 5666: FILTERED'
+ PortOut='Port 5666: FILTERED'
+ [[ '' -eq 1 ]]
+ PortOut=N/A
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ cmd_NRPE
++ sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 10.x.x.x 
+ NRPEtmp='CHECK_NRPE STATE CRITICAL: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.'
++ echo 'CHECK_NRPE STATE CRITICAL: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.'
++ awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'
+ NRPEnix=CHECK_NRPE
++ echo 'CHECK_NRPE STATE CRITICAL: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.'
++ cut -d ' ' -f4-
+ NRPEwin='Socket timeout after 10 seconds.'
+ [[ CHECK_NRPE = \N\R\P\E ]]
+ [[ Socket timeout after 10 seconds. = \s\e\e\m\ \t\o\ \b\e\ \d\o\i\n\g\ \f\i\n\e\.\.\. ]]
++ echo -e 'NPRE: Not Configured'
+ NRPEOut='NPRE: Not Configured'
+ echo -e ', 10.x.x.x , Ping: FAILED, N/A, NPRE: Not Configured'
, 10.x.x.x , Ping: FAILED, N/A, NPRE: Not Configured
```

If you go through the output of bash -x, you will otice that the function cmd_NMAP somehow evaluates the conditions for IF and ELSE as true. What baffled me is there is that condition " [[ '' -eq 1 ]]" which I don't know where it comes from.

I have a feeling that this is something simple that I have somehow overlook but I've been at it for hours now and i somehow can't see it. I've even checked using ShellCheck and it tells me all is good.

All help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't `[[ '' -eq 1 ]]` from the check before `cmd_TNET`? `$CheckPort2` isn't set anywhere, so this seems to behave as expected, no?

Comment: (It being unset is the only ShellCheck warning, it seems.)

Comment: The trace clearly shows that the `nmap`-invoking function executes only one case of its `if/elif/else` ladder, showing `FILTERED`.

Comment: I see what you mean. The caller of that function is also setting `PortOut=n/a`. Here is the thing; it can't be in the same `if/else`.

Comment: hi @BenjaminW. - there used to be a function called for the telnet.  I have now fixed the problem. will proceed to close it. thanks again.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is wrong with your logic is, let's see:

```
    if [[ "$CheckPort" -eq 1 ]]; then
        cmd_NMAP
    else   # ($CheckPort -ne 1)
        PortOut='N/A' 
    fi

    if [[ "$CheckPort2" -eq 1 ]]; then 
        cmd_TNET
    else 
        PortOut='N/A'
    fi
```

What happens if `CheckPort` is `1`, but `ChecPort2` is other than `1`?

The first `if` statement will execute `cmd_NMAP` which will set up `PortOut`. But immediately after that, the next `if` statement will execute its `else` and clobber `PortOut`.

If you want all these cases to be exclusive, do it another way. Perhaps you wanted this?

```
    if [[ "$CheckPort" -eq 1 ]]; then
        cmd_NMAP
    elif [[ "$CheckPort2" -eq 1 ]]; then 
        cmd_TNET
    else 
        PortOut='N/A'
    fi
```

Only if none of the `CheckPort*` variables are true, then we fall back on setting `PortOut` to `N/A`.

Evidence from your log that it's the second `if` statement:

`cmd_NMAP` is called:

```
++ sudo nmap -Pn -p 5666 10.119.4.106
++ grep 5666
++ awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }'
+ PortStatus=filtered
+ [[ filtered = \o\p\e\n ]]
+ [[ filtered = \f\i\l\t\e\r\e\d ]]
```

`cmd_NMAP` assigns the variable and returns:

```
++ echo -e 'Port 5666: FILTERED'
+ PortOut='Port 5666: FILTERED'
```

And the next `if` statement is now testing `$CheckPort2`, which is blank, thus executes the `else` which clobbers `PortOut` to `N/A`:

```
+ [[ '' -eq 1 ]]
+ PortOut=N/A
```